# ACTION_SEND app list is short

Tags: android-intent, android

I am working on an Android app. One of the functionality is to send content to friends via user's installed apps. Here's my code:

```
Intent testMessageIntent = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
testMessageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here is my shared url: "+"http://www.google.com/");
testMessageIntent.setType("plain/text");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(testMessageIntent, "Share with your friend:"));
```

Here's what I get on Screen:

[image]

This seems pretty good, but not as good as I want. In Android Jelly app, they have a far longer list to send:

[image]

And this list goes on and on, covers all my apps that can send stuff (WhatsApp, FB, Tumblr, Skype, Twitter, etc).

How can I get such a list in my app share functionality? Is Jelly using a different intent? or do they do anything special?

Comment: This intent show only installed apps on device which have sharing features.

Comment: Try `text/plain` in place of `plain/text`.

Comment: Would you mark my answer if I post one now? I say this cos the accepted answer below is a duplicate(verbatim) of my comment.

Comment: @Mrinali yeah please go ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mistakenly used `plain/text` as an argument here:

```
testMessageIntent.setType("plain/text");
```

The mime-type you need is `text/plain`.

An aside from [developer pages](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html):

> Note: MIME type matching in the Android framework is case-sensitive,
>   unlike formal RFC MIME types. As a result, you should always specify
>   MIME types using lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

Your set mimetype is incorrect. Try with this one instead.

```
testMessageIntent.setType("text/plain");
```